# PHP MySQL join 3 tables and output result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I have three tables as follows:

Items:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|  itemID  |  itemName  |  categoryID  |  sellerID  |
-----------------------------------------------------
|  1       |  item1     |  c1          |  s1        |
|  2       |  item2     |  c1          |  s2        |
|  3       |  item3     |  c3          |  s2        |
|  4       |  item4     |  c2          |  s3        |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Categories:

```
---------------------------------
|  categoryID  |  categoryName  |
---------------------------------
|  c1          |  category1     |
|  c2          |  category2     |
|  c3          |  category3     |
---------------------------------
```

Seller:

```
-----------------------------
|  sellerID  |  sellerName  |
-----------------------------
|  s1        |  seller1     |
|  s2        |  seller2     |
|  s3        |  seller3     |
-----------------------------
```

I want to select items from the **`Items`** table where categoryID is **`c1`** and display it as follows:

```
----------------------------------------------
|  itemName  |  categoryName  |  sellerName  |
----------------------------------------------
|  item1     |  category1     |  seller1     |
|  item2     |  category1     |  seller2     |
----------------------------------------------
```

I can't figure out how to do it. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

```
SELECT i.itemName, c.categoryName, s.sellerName
FROM Items i
JOIN Categories c
  ON c.id = i.categoryID
JOIN Seller s
  ON s.id = i.sellerID
WHERE i.categoryID = 'c1'
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I had written almost the same query. The only difference was that I was using `INNER JOIN` instead of `JOIN`. I guess I have to research it thoroughly and understand the basic difference between all the different types of joins. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join) question about join differences.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select items.itemName, categories.categoryName, seller.sellerName
from items
join categories on items.categoryId = categories.categoryId
join seller on items.sellerId = seller.sellerId
where categories.categoryId = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT itemName, categories.categoryName, seller.sellerName 
FROM items 
INNER JOIN categories ON items.categoryID = categories.categoryID 
INNER JOIN seller ON items.sellerID = seller.sellerID 
WHERE items.categoryID = 'c1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$strSql = 'SELECT a.`itemName`,b.`categoryName`,c.`sellerName` FROM `Items` a INNER JOIN `Categories` b ON a.`categoryID` = b.`categoryID`
         INNER JOIN `Seller` c ON a.`sellerID` = c.`sellerID` WHERE a.`categoryID` = "c1" ';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of creating the correct joins.  In this case, you need to attach the tables to two different things.  The syntax should look like this:

```
$stmt = 'SELECT a.itemName,b.categoryName,c.sellerName FROM `[itemsTable]`
    inner join a  on b.categoryID  = a.categoryID  
inner join a on c.sellerID = a.sellerID';
```